# Save 4d numpy array as pcd(point cloud) file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, open3d

How can I convert a 4d numpy array to a pcd file? Open3d appears to let you save 3 dimensions but not a fourth(intensity).

Comment: which program do you expect to read the 4d data back in ? and where do you get those values from ?

Comment: it is [a simple txt format, similar to pcl](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.html) you can write your own exporter in a few lines of code

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible using the [open3d.t](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.t.html) namespace:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

xyzi = np.random.rand(100, 4)

xyz = xyzi[:,0:3]
i = [[i] for i in xyzi[:,3]]

pcd = o3d.t.geometry.PointCloud()

pcd.point["positions"] = o3d.core.Tensor(xyz)
pcd.point["intensities"] = o3d.core.Tensor(i)

o3d.t.io.write_point_cloud("pointcloud.pcd", pcd)
```

For more info see [this thread](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/438).